# How to Replace/Overwrite only certain values in Snowflake Table?

Tags: sql, sql-insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, overwrite, snowflake-schema

I have a Snowflake SQL command in the form of:

```
CREATE TASK REPLACE_CERTAIN_ROWS
WAREHOUSE=<MY_WAREHOUSE>
SCHEDULE='USING CRON 0 5,17 * * * UTC'
AS
insert overwrite into <MY_SCHEMA>.<MY_TABLE>(FIELD1,FIELD2)
<MY_SQL>
```

And my table looks like:

```
FIELD1|FIELD2
ABC,REPLACE
DEF,REPLACE
GHI,DONTREPLACE
JKL,DONTREPLACE
```

Instead of replacing the entire table how can I alter my Snowflake to only overwrite the FIELD2="REPLACE" rows? Do I have to first have a command that deletes these rows or is there a way to do it more instantaneously? I know I can only execute one command per Snowflake task so would like to avoid managing dependent tasks and do it all in the same task/command.

Desired Result:

```
FIELD1|FIELD2
GHI,DONTREPLACE <- remained
JKL,DONTREPLACE <- remained
MNO,REPLACE <- was replaced
PQR,REPLACE <- was replaced
```

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/update.html) is the normal way to do this:

```
UPDATE <MYDB>.<MY_SCHEMA>.<MY_TABLE> SET field1 = <new value> WHERE field2 = 'REPLACE';
```

but if you are trying to drive this from a TABLE/STREAM then [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#duplicate-join-behavior) is more what you will want.

Comment: Thank you (for all your SO SQL answers). Can you put this in the context of the first CREATE TASK block I posted. I’m having trouble with how to structure my existing task with MERGE/UPDATE